# Confidence value in AdaBoost?

Tags: machine-learning

I read this introduction about AdaBoost (http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~nikolaon/~nikolaon_files/Introduction_to_AdaBoost.pdf), and am curious why confidence for each model is defined as

$$\alpha_j=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1-\epsilon_j}{\epsilon_j}$$

(from page 48 of http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~nikolaon/~nikolaon_files/Introduction_to_AdaBoost.pdf).

Could anyone provide any source for explaining this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can think AdaBoost algorithm as a example of additive modeling using exponential loss function,  the confidence for each model is calculated to minimize the loss function at each step. 
reference:   https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/boosting.pdf

Comment: Try out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsK-xG1cLYA (6:16 to 10:40)